# Slow performance in Mongoose after upgrading from 3.5.7 to 3.8.4

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I changed the version number of mongoose from 3.5.7 to 3.8.4 and performance took a huge hit in an import process. This process reads lines from a file and populates an empty database (no indexes) with about 2.5 million rows.

This is the only change I've made; just upgrading the version. I can switch back and forth and see the difference in performance.

The performance hits are: 1) The process pegs at 100% CPU, where before it ran upwards of maybe 25% or so. 2) Entry into the database into the database is slow. 3.5.7 inserted about 10K records every 20 seconds while 3.8.4 seems to be inserting at more around 1 per second. 3) nodejs seems to "disappear" into something CPU intensive and all other I/O functions get blocked (http requests, etc.); previously the system remained very responsive.

It's hard to isolate the code, but roughly here's what's happening:

- Read a line from a file
- Parse it
- Run a query to see if the record already exists
- Insert/update a record with the values from the line read
- Write the existing record to an already-open file stream
- Continue with the next line in the file

At a guess, I would say it's related to a change in how requests are throttled either in the underlying driver that mongoose depends on or mongoose itself. My first thought was to try and handle the case where requests are getting queued up and put a pause on the file read. This works really well when writing the results of a query (pausing the querystream when the file starts caching writes, then resuming on drain). But I haven't been able to find where mongoose might be emitting information about its back-pressure.

The reason I upgraded in the first place is because of a memory leak error I was getting when setting an event handled in mongoose that I had read was fixed (sorry I lost reference to that).

I'd like to stay upgraded and figure out the issue. Any thoughts on what it might be? Is there an event given somewhere that notifies me of back-pressure so I can pause/resume the input stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by simply reverting back to 3.5.7 and solving the original memory leak warnings another way.

I attempted to isolate my code, but the worst issue I was able to raise was high memory consumption (which I resolved by nulling objects, which apparently helps the GC figure out what it can collect). I started adding in unrelated code, but at some point it became clear that the issue wasn't with mongoose or the mongodb driver itself.

My only guess on what really causes the performance issue when I upgrade mongoose is that some library depended on by mongoose introduced a change that my non-mongoose-related code isn't playing well with.

If I ever get to the bottom of it, I'll come back and post a clearer answer.